# Kibana: Set a scripted field as time field name

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I have a time-based Kibana and the time-field is a type [number] (e.g. 1599026948 ) called **timestamp**. The **time field name** is not set and I need to set it to timestamp. Because of the bad format (number) of timestamp, I created a scripted field called **datetime** to get a better date-format.
The code for the scripted field **datetime**:

```
doc['timestamp'].value * 1000;
```

It works as it should:

```
Samples
Input                   Output
1599027119802           Sep 2, 2020 @ 08:11:59.802
1577833200000           Jan 1, 2020 @ 00:00:00.000
1609455599999           Dec 31, 2020 @ 23:59:59.999
```

When I look at my "Discover"-tab, I get the warning:
**"1 of 2 shards failed The data you are seeing might be incomplete or wrong."**

**Warning-detail:**

```
script_exception at shard 0 index MY-INDEX-PATTERN node JgWo2yNxRBeR9mEuYLpK2R

Type               script_exeption
Reason             runtime error
Script stack       org.elasticsearch.search.lookup.LeafDocLookup.get(LeafDocLookup.java:94)
                   org.elasticsearch.search.lookup.LeafDocLookup.get(LeafDocLookup.java:41)
                   doc['timestamp'].value * 1000;
                       ^---- HERE

Script             doc['timestamp'].value * 1000;
Lang               painless
Caused by type     illegal_argument_exeption
Caused by reason   No field found for [timestamp] in mapping with types []
```

I ignored the warning and moved on.
I needed to set the **time field name** to the new field **datetime**.

I tried this by following code in the **console**:

```
POST .kibana/_update/MY-INDEX-PATTERN
{
  "doc": {
    "index-pattern": {
      "timeFieldName" : "datetime"
    }
  }
}
```

I get the following result:

```
{
  "_index" : ".kibana",
  "_type" : "_doc",
  "_id" : "MY-INDEX-PATTERN",
  "_version" : 8,
  "result" : "updated",
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 2,
    "successful" : 2,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "_seq_no" : 887,
  "_primary_term" : 4
}
```

Looks like it worked, but when i try to create a time-based component inside my dashboard or just change the **time-filter**, it does not work and i get the same warning as above (*1 of 2 shards failed..*)

I think the **time field name** was not set to datetime.

I feel like I tried everything but nothing workes. I really want to avoid **reindexing** or is this the only solution? I am new to Kibana and hope someone can help me.

-Tobi

Answer (score 0):

Solved: Kibana-administrator has to reindex the index, and set the type of timestamp to date. Now timestamp is visible when creating a pattern and can be choosen for **time field name**.